# Extract row indexes of non-empty cells in specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract row indexes of non-empty cells in range("A1:A10") which has a name "data", range("Ai") (`i` is even number) has value "long" and range("Aj") (`j` is odd number) is empty cell. If I do it right I should get (2,4,6,8,10), but my code failed. Here is my code:

```
Sub RowIndexes()
   Dim NonEmptyRows As Integer
   Dim RowIndexes() As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim rng As Range

   NonEmptyRows = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("data"), "long")
   ReDim RowIndexes(1 To NonEmptyRows)

   For Each rng In Range("data")
       If rng.Value = "long" Then
           i = i + 1
           RowIndexes(i) = rng.Row
       End If
   Next rng

   Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B5").Value = RowIndexes
End Sub
```

I printed it out but the result confused me, I just got "2" (it may be the row index of range("A2")) and I can't figure out why. Really need some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Range("data")
    If rng.Value = "long" Then
        i = i + 1
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & (Range("B" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).Row+1)).Value = rng.Row
    End If
Next rng
```

Tested and the results I got in `Range B` was

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

If however you want to use your existing code then you need to update the following lines

**OLD** LINE

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B5").Value = RowIndexes
```

**NEW EDITED** LINES

```
For i = 1 To NonEmptyRows
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & (Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value = RowIndexes(i)
   Next i
```

The old `RowIndexes` does not account for all the sub variables as in `1 to Number of NonEmptyRows` it by default picks up the first variable which is `RowIndexes(1)` whose value is `2`

Comment: thanks for the instructions and I fixed this problem which postponed my project for two days. With your inspiration I digged a little bit further and found something interesting.

Comment: If you create a array and assign some values to it manually, it seems to be "row vector" and if you want to print it out you either use Range("whatever").value=worksheetfunction.transpose(MyArray) or a for loop. But if you transfer the range values to array , it seems to be "column vector" or "matrix",you can just print it out by using Range("whatever").value=MyArray(they have the same rows and columns). I wonder if there were a general pattern?